# Transform part of string in Array Key

Tags: php, arrays, string, key

Ok, I'm have some troubles with a form. The form receive a array looking like this:

```
Array (
[0] => abajur-grande } abajur grande
[1] => lustre-bem-grande } lustre bem grande
)
```

This info is send by this field of the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="campo[]" value="<?php echo $urlprod;?> } <?php echo $nome;?><br />" />
```

So, what I wanna do is transform the first part of each value in the key of the array, like this, and remove the "}":

```
Array (
[abajur-grande] => abajur grande
[lustre-bem-grande] => lustre bem grande
)
```

Someone have a idea?

Comment: just remove this part of the form: `} <?php echo $nome;?>`

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem... you're looking for a way to fix the result of broken code, instead of looking into ways to fix the broken code itself. Remove the `}` chars from the markup, that would be my recommendation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a foreach-loop to solve this.

```
$arr = array(
    'abajur-grande } abajur grande',
    'lustre-bem-grande } lustre bem grande'
);

$newArr = array();
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $parts = explode(' } ', $value);
    if(count($parts) > 1) {
        $newArr[$parts[0]] = $parts[1];
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: Look at how the hidden field is given its value... clearly that is what is causing problems in the first place. If there's an issue, don't work around it -> fix it. Looping over data to fix bad formatting _you caused_ is like patching the tires _you_ sliced

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the array and take each value, split it based on `}` and assign the first part as key and second part as value to a new array.

```
$oldArr = array("abajur-grande } abajur grande",
                "lustre-bem-grande } lustre bem grande");   
$newArr = array();

foreach($oldArr as $key) //loop old array and retrieve each element inside $key
{
    //split $key into two pieces by "}"    
    $split = explode("}",$key); 
    //assign the first piece as key and second as value into a new array
    $newArr[$split[0]]= $split[1]; 

}
print_r($newArr);
```